# Javascript: Promises + this

Tags: javascript, promise, this

Consider the following code:

```
foo: function() {
  var self = this;
  var p1 = p2 = someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise();

  Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(self.bar);
}

bar: function(promises) {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self);
}
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

But if I do the following instead:

```
foo: function() {
  var self = this;
  var p1 = p2 = someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise();

  Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(function(result) {
      self.bar(result);
    });
}

bar: function(promises) {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self);
}
```

Output:

```
{ foo: [Function],
  bar: [Function] }
```

I don't understand why the first call changes where **this** points in the bar function. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Because it's very important how you call a function. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this In your first example you "detouched" method from context object, so you lost it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with promises, see [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) for other solutions

Comment: @dfsq: I wouldn't even use the term "detouched". There are no methods in JS, functions become them only when being called as object properties. They're unbound otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass `self.bar` to the `then` method, you pass a function reference. Although it looks like you also specify it should be called on the `self` object, that is actually not what is happening. The `self` object is not included in that function reference. The `this` object's value is determined when a function is called, not when it is defined or passed as argument.

In your second example, `self` *is* the `this` object within the function context, because that is where you *call* the function from.

Another way to get it working is to force the function's `this` object to always be `self`, overriding the above described behaviour. You can achieve that with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(self.bar.bind(self));
```